# Creating a frozen object for modules outside

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

```
class Model {
 this.prop1 = "someKey",
 this.prop2 = "someKey1",

  anyMethod(valueForProp1, valueForProp2) {
         this.prop1 = valueForProp1;
         this.prop2 = valueForProp2;
  }
}

exports.createModel = () => new Model();
```

The logic I am trying to create with the above code is as follows;

I do not want to give direct access to this class from any external module.In other words, new properties cannot be added to the objects of this class, and also the existing properties (like `prop1`, `prop2`) cannot be changed.The properties of objects of this class can only be changed by the methods(like `anyMethod`) in this module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS doesn't support `private` members/methods yet. So currently you are unable to force this kind of functionality.

The most agreed-upon convention (for JS) is to add a prefix of `_` to any "private" members.

```js
class Model {
 this._prop1 = "someKey",
 this._prop2 = "someKey1",

  anyMethod(valueForProp1, valueForProp2) {
         this._prop1 = valueForProp1;
         this._prop2 = valueForProp2;
  }
}

exports.createModel = () => new Model();
```

Outer solutions usually involve a 3rd party **static type checker** (like Typescript or flow) but this adds additional complexity to the code base that I don't know if you like or need.